# Excel formula cumulative objective

Tags: excel, formula

I need a way to do cumulative objectives.
Let's see, I have the objective to sell 100 bananas today.
On the first day, I sold 100 bananas, so the second day the objective stay the same.
On the second day, I sold 99 bananas, so on the third day the objective will be 101.
On the third day I sold 102 bananas, so on the forth day the objective will be 99, etc...

Comment: This is not really a question about formulas, this is more a question on basic spreadsheet design. You need to show examples of what you've got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will put your objectives in column A:

Put 100 in A1 manually. Put this formula in A2 and fill it down:

```
=A1+100-B1
```

Put the number of bananas sold each day in column B, starting in B1.